# How to merge two data frames based on nearest date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two data frames based on two columns: "Code" and "Date". It is straightforward to merge data frames based on "Code", however in case of "Date" it becomes tricky - there is no exact match between Dates in df1 and df2. So, I want to select closest Dates. How can I do this?

```
df = df1[column_names1].merge(df2[column_names2], on='Code')
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614474/pandas-merge-on-name-and-closest-date

Comment: Here is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201618/pandas-merge-match-the-nearest-time-stamp-the-series-of-timestamps

Comment: @jakevdp: Thanks, but how can I combine it with merging by Code? Should I first use "searchsorted" and then put "mask = idx >= 0 &..."?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a quick, one-line way to do this kind of thing but I belive the best approach is to do it this way:

1. add a column to `df1` with the closest date from the appropriate group in `df2`
2. call a standard merge on these

As the size of your data grows, this "closest date" operation can become rather expensive unless you do something sophisticated. I like to use scikit-learn's [`NearestNeighbor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) code for this sort of thing.

I've put together one approach to that solution that should scale relatively well.
First we can generate some simple data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('2015', periods=200, freq='D')

rand = np.random.RandomState(42)
i1 = np.sort(rand.permutation(np.arange(len(dates)))[:5])
i2 = np.sort(rand.permutation(np.arange(len(dates)))[:5])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Code': rand.randint(0, 2, 5),
                    'Date': dates[i1],
                    'val1':rand.rand(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Code': rand.randint(0, 2, 5),
                    'Date': dates[i2],
                    'val2':rand.rand(5)})
```

Let's check these out:

```
>>> df1
   Code       Date      val1
0     0 2015-01-16  0.975852
1     0 2015-01-31  0.516300
2     1 2015-04-06  0.322956
3     1 2015-05-09  0.795186
4     1 2015-06-08  0.270832

>>> df2
   Code       Date      val2
0     1 2015-02-03  0.184334
1     1 2015-04-13  0.080873
2     0 2015-05-02  0.428314
3     1 2015-06-26  0.688500
4     0 2015-06-30  0.058194
```

Now let's write an `apply` function that adds a column of nearest dates to `df1` using scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

def find_nearest(group, match, groupname):
    match = match[match[groupname] == group.name]
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(1).fit(match['Date'].values[:, None])
    dist, ind = nbrs.kneighbors(group['Date'].values[:, None])

    group['Date1'] = group['Date']
    group['Date'] = match['Date'].values[ind.ravel()]
    return group

df1_mod = df1.groupby('Code').apply(find_nearest, df2, 'Code')
>>> df1_mod
   Code       Date      val1      Date1
0     0 2015-05-02  0.975852 2015-01-16
1     0 2015-05-02  0.516300 2015-01-31
2     1 2015-04-13  0.322956 2015-04-06
3     1 2015-04-13  0.795186 2015-05-09
4     1 2015-06-26  0.270832 2015-06-08
```

Finally, we can merge these together with a straightforward call to `pd.merge`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1_mod, df2, on=['Code', 'Date'])
   Code       Date      val1      Date1      val2
0     0 2015-05-02  0.975852 2015-01-16  0.428314
1     0 2015-05-02  0.516300 2015-01-31  0.428314
2     1 2015-04-13  0.322956 2015-04-06  0.080873
3     1 2015-04-13  0.795186 2015-05-09  0.080873
4     1 2015-06-26  0.270832 2015-06-08  0.688500
```

Notice that rows 0 and 1 both matched the same `val2`; this is expected given the way you described your desired solution.

Comment: Not related to this question but your PYCON 2015 SKLEARN was very nice. Much appreciated for sharing!

Comment: I have a problem with dates in the format: 2015-10-19T07:42:00.000 Do you have any idea how to parse them so that the code works?

Comment: You can convert from string to date with ``pd.to_datetime()``

Comment: Is there a way to modify `find_nearest` so that it takes less parameters and matches on date only?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

1. Merge on Code.
2. Add a date difference column according to your need (I used abs in the example below) and sort the data using the new column.
3. Group by the records of the first data frame and for each group take a record from the second data frame with the closest date.

Code:

```
df = df1.reset_index()[column_names1].merge(df2[column_names2], on='Code')
df['DateDiff'] = (df['Date1'] - df['Date2']).abs()
df.sort_values('DateDiff').groupby('index').first().reset_index()
```