# Finding row with nearest timestamp that matches id, and add row with value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, and would like to insert a row into df1 with a value from df2, based on the nearest datetime and matching ID. Example df's below:

```
df1
  storeID   datetime
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00

df2
  storeID   datetime              Value
0 111       2020-01-01 00:55:00   1
1 111       2020-01-05 01:00:00   2
2 222       2020-01-10 05:50:00   3
3 222       2020-01-15 04:55:00   4
4 333       2020-01-20 10:10:00   5
5 333       2020-01-20 11:00:00   6
```

The output should be something like this:

```
df1
  storeID   datetime              Value
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00   1
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00   4
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00   5
```

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833362/merge-dataframes-on-nearest-datetime-timestamp), which is quite similar, however, it is not considering that ID's should match. In the real example do df1 have 50.000+ rows and df2 has 200.000+ rows.

Answer (score 1):

Merge is not exactly the solution to this. Use `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='datetime', by='storeID', direction='nearest')
```

Output:

```
   storeID            datetime  Value
0      111 2020-01-01 00:50:00      1
1      222 2020-01-05 05:00:00      3
2      333 2020-01-10 10:00:00      5
```

Comment: It merges now, however, in the value column, i get mostly NaN values - maybe 1% i correct. A few merges correctly, but cannot figure out the reason for this, as the values is present in both columns. I tried looking through the documentation, but none of the parameters and tried setting a tolerance, but this did not work. Any suggestions?