# merge_asof gives NaN values in added columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360176/finding-row-with-nearest-timestamp-that-matches-id-and-add-row-with-value) earlier, about merging dataframes on nearest datetime and by ID and was suggested merge_asof, but i get NaN values in columns. Example df's below:

```
df1
  ID1       active_at
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00.000
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00.000
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00.000

df2
  ID2       timeObserved          Value
0 111       2020-01-01 00:55:00   1
1 111       2020-01-05 01:00:00   2
2 222       2020-01-10 05:50:00   3
3 222       2020-01-15 04:55:00   4
4 333       2020-01-20 10:10:00   5
5 333       2020-01-20 11:00:00   6
```

I wanted to get a result similar to:

```
df3
  ID1       active_at                 Value
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00.000   1
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00.000   4
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00.000   5
```

or

```
df3
  ID1       active_at                 Value    ID2    timeObserved
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00.000   1        111    2020-01-01 00:55:00
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00.000   4        222    2020-01-15 04:55:00
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00.000   5        333    2020-01-20 10:10:00
```

I used this to merge them:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2, left_on='active_at', right_on='timeObserved', left_by='ID1', 
         right_by='ID2', direction='nearest')
```

But i am getting this result:

```
df1
  ID1       active_at                 Value    ID2    timeObserved
0 111       2020-01-01 00:50:00.000   NaN      NaN    NaT
1 222       2020-01-05 05:00:00.000   NaN      Nan    Nat
2 333       2020-01-10 10:00:00.000   5        333    2020-01-20 10:10:00
```

On the real data, i get 2 out of 50 merged by ID's correctly.
I am sure there is matching ID's, which is why i am wondering.

I have tried:
Setting the tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2d')to multiple days.
Double checked that the dType is correct before merging. dateTime64[ns] on 'active_at' and 'timeObserved' , and int on 'value' and 'ID'.
Made sure there is matching ID's.

When i use the df3.info(), i notice that the dType of 'Value' and 'ID2' has changed to float64. I cannot figure out why, is it because of the NaN values or some mistake i have made?

There is 2.732 rows in df1 and 40.500 in df2.

Comment: Which pandas version are you using. For me with 1.1.3 your code gives the desired result.

Comment: What Python version do you have?

Comment: I am using version 1.1.2 of pandas, and python version 3.8.6