# How to merge 2 pandas data frames and update a column with latest value from 2 matched rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 2 pandas data frames which have multiple columns.

Some rows have same values in all columns except one column which is `updated_at`.

I need to merge 2 data frames and consider the latest `updated_at` value from matched rows. `updated_at` is a datetime value.

I found a way to merge data frames but not sure how to use the latest value for `updated_at` column.

```
pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    how="inner",
    on=["column_1", "column_2", "column_3"])
```

Here's sample input for `df1` and `df2`.

**df1:**

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date       updated_at 
1          1234       John       Doe  01/02/1999  04/12/2002 6:00 PM   
2          2345     Joanne       Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 7:22 PM   
3          3456  Annabelle     Jones  01/02/2001  04/21/2002 5:00 PM
```

**df2:**

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date       updated_at 
1          1234       John       Doe  01/02/1999  04/12/2002 5:00 PM   
2          2345     Joanne       Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 8:22 PM
```

**final_output:**

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date       updated_at 
1          1234       John       Doe  01/02/1999  04/12/2002 6:00 PM   
2          2345     Joanne       Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 8:22 PM   
3          3456  Annabelle     Jones  01/02/2001  04/21/2002 5:00 PM
```

Notice the `updated_at` column is having latest value from matched records.

Comment: It will depend on what is the `latest` value, right? The rest is just merging and making a decision which one to keep (from df1 or df2). Is it the case where df2 will always have the 'updated_at' considered to be 'latest'?

Comment: `df2` doesn't always have the latest `updated_at` value. Sometimes it could be in matched row in `df1`.

Comment: I think you'd need to elaborate a bit more on input and expected output. Otherwise it's alot of guessing involved. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Updated question with input and expected output.

Comment: Have you seen this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614474/pandas-merge-on-name-and-closest-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that can do the job ...

Just make sure your `updated_at` column is set as `datetime`

```
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('updated_at').drop_duplicates(subset=df1.columns[:-1],keep='last').sort_values('MRN')
    MRN Encounter_ID First_Name   Last_Name  Birth_Date          updated_at
1  1234         John        Doe  01/02/1999  04/12/2002 2020-12-31 06:00:00
2  2345       Joanne        Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 2020-12-31 08:22:00
3  3456    Annabelle      Jones  01/02/2001  04/21/2002 2020-12-31 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that will accomplish this task, I'm pretty sure. Instead of using a merge, use a `concat`, then a `groupby` with an `agg`, as follows.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Joe'], 'Val':['1','3']})

   Name Val
0  John   1
1   Joe   3

B = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Joe'], 'Val':['4','2']})

   Name Val
0  John   4
1   Joe   2

C = pd.concat([A,B]).groupby('Name').agg('max').reset_index()

   Name Val
0   Joe   3
1  John   4
```

In this example the `Val` column corresponds to your `updated_at` columns and the `Name` column is all the columns that you want to match to group together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include rows from one dataframe not present in the other, then you don't want `inner` in the merge, you'll need `how='outer'`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=df1.columns[:-1].tolist())
```

Then you can get the last update with:

```
df['updated_at'] = df[['updated_at_x', 'updated_at_y']].max(axis=1)
```

and drop the unnecessary columns:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['updated_at_x', 'updated_at_y'])
```

Output:

```
   MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date          updated_at
0    1          1234       John       Doe  01/02/1999 2002-04-12 18:00:00
1    2          2345     Joanne       Lee  04/19/2002 2002-04-19 20:22:00
2    3          3456  Annabelle     Jones  01/02/2001 2002-04-21 17:00:00
```